# How to run thread continuously in java

Tags: java

I'm new for java, I want to run thread continuously before that I want to check if that same thread running already means stop and run again. Please anyone help me!

Here my code:

```
public class TripTrackService {

    private static class TripThread implements Runnable {
        private final Thread t;

        TripThread() {
            t = new Thread ();
            t.setName("hello");
        }
        public void start() {
            if( !t.isAlive())
            {
                t.start();
            System.out.println(t.getName()+ " Running....."+t.isAlive());
            Thread th = getThreadByName("hello");
                if(th!=null)
                System.out.println(th.getName()+"Already  Running....."+th.isAlive());
                else
                    System.out.println("No thread Found");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Already  Running.....");
                Thread th = getThreadByName("test");
                if(th!=null){
                    System.out.println(th.getName()+"Else Already  Running....."+th.isAlive());
                    th.interrupt();
                }               
                else{
                    System.out.println("No thread Found");
                }                    
            }               
        }
        public void stop() {   
            if(t.isAlive())
            t.stop();           
        }
        public void run()  {
            if(!t.isAlive())
            t.run();                             
        }
        public Thread getThreadByName(String threadName){
            Thread _tmp = null;
            Set<Thread> threadSet = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
            Thread[] array =  threadSet.toArray(new Thread[threadSet.size()]);
            for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
               // System.out.println(array[i].getName());
                if(array[i].getName().equals(threadName)){
                    _tmp=array[i];
                }
            }
            return _tmp;
        }      
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {        
       TripThread myThread = new TripThread ();   
       myThread.start();  
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: so whats problem with your current code ?

Comment: Its not print stament continuously...

Comment: you should be writing your logic in the `run()` method and start the thread by calling `thread.start()` which will call the `run()` method asynchronously. Even so, I don't understand what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Sorry to ask this.. Can you edit my code for my understanding.

Comment: @hikoo To get a better understanding of what SamuelKok meant, take a look at http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/creating-and-starting-threads.html It should help you get a better understanding on how to  use threads in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Here your Thread t does not have a job to do, so just assign it by changing your constructor like this (by overriding the run method).

```
ThreadBehaviour() {
        t = new Thread(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("running");
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        t.setName("hello");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As requested in the mentioned comment, a sample thread should look like this.

```
public class SampleThreadRunner 
{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        SampleThread sampleThread1 = new SampleThread("Thread1");
        SampleThread sampleThread2 = new SampleThread("Thread2");
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(sampleThread1);
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(sampleThread2);
        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
    }
}

class SampleThread implements Runnable{

    private String threadName;
    private int counter;

    public SampleThread(String threadName){
        this.threadName = threadName;
    }
    public void run()
    {
        while(counter < 1000){
            System.out.println("Printing " + threadName + " Count: " + counter++);    
        }

    }  
}
```

Or like the previous answer.

P.S: Didn't had the time to create a Git Repo to link a sample, probably will do so around evening.

Answer (score 0):

```
Thread thread = new Thread("Thread Name") {
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            //your code 
        }
    }
};
thread.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

class DigitalClock extends Thread
{

```
public void run()
{
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        LocalDateTime todayDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
        System.out.println(todayDateTime);
        Thread t=new DigitalClock();
        t.start();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

public class App4{
/**
* @param args
*/
public static void main(String[] args) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Thread t=new DigitalClock();
t.isDaemon();
t.setPriority(4);
t.start();
}
}